# Implementing the length function with zf notation

Tags: haskell

How can I implement the length function in Haskell by using list comprehension? An example.

```
take [x| x<- [1,2,3], even]
```

Comment: What’s ‘zf notation’? It’s certainly not a term I’m aware of. Also, does your code sample have anything to do with your question?

Comment: You can't implement the `length` function using a list comprehension. A list comprehension can only produce a list!

Comment: @bradrn, maybe it refers to the similarity between list comprehension notation and set comprehensions in (e.g., Zermelo-Fraenkel) set theory?

Comment: @dfeuer You might be able to do something hacky with `-XParallelListComp`? But yes, this isn’t something you can do in ‘traditional’ list comprehensions.

Comment: @dfeuer Hmm, maybe? But I don’t really know much about ZF set theory.

Comment: @bradrn, I don't see how that would help either.

Comment: @dfeuer I’m thinking something along the lines of `maximum [ n | _ <- list | n <- [0..] ]`, though that fails for null `list`.

Comment: `[ () | _ <- xs ]` returns a list's length *in unary notation*. So does `[ x | x <- xs ]` or simply `xs`.

Comment: Clever @WillNess! Of course unary notation makes this problem trivial…

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, if you want an integer as the output, it is not possible to calculate the length of a list using *only* a list comprehension because a list comprehension produces a list.  However there are some ways to use a list comprehension *and* an additional function to get the length.  The classic way to do this has been

```hs
length x =
  sum [ 1 | _ <- x ]
```

This replaces every element in the list with `1` and then takes the sum.

Another somewhat straight forward way to do this is:

```hs
length x =
  last [ i | (_, i) <- zip (undefined : x) [0 ..] ]
```

Here we extend the list by 1, replace every element in the list with its index using a list comprehension and take the last index.  You can also substitute `maximum` in place of `last` and this will work.

There are also much more exotic ways that one can dream up

```hs
length x =
  foldr ($) 0 [ (+1) | _ <- x ]
```

but there are far too many of these for me to list.

Overall these are probably not a very idiomatic or practical way to get the length of a list.  Aside from the first one which I see done in some contexts, I don't think anyone would implement length any of these ways.